# Connecting QLCDNumber to a QSpinBox

Tags: c++

I am writing a program that gets a number from a spinBox and converts it into Binary by clicking the "convert" button that I have created.
I have been trying to get the QLCDNumber to read the number in from the QSpinBox.
This is the code I entered:

```
connect(convert, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(pushButtonClicked()));
```

I have implemented the pushButtonClicked() function as follows:

```
void myClass::pushButtonClicked()
{
    m_LCD1->setBinMode();
    m_LCD1->display(input->value());
}
```

But for some reason when I run the program and click on the "convert" button nothing happens! Please someone help!

Answer (score 0):

There could be a couple things happening.  But my guess is that you've omitted 'slots' in your .h file:

```
public slots:
    void pushButtonClicked();
```

Without that, the code will compile and run, but the function isn't a slot.  So the 'connect' command will fail.

Comment: Thank you for your response but I just checked again and I did that. I did put void pushButtonClicked() in my header file under public slots. Any other possible suggestions?